# Why does my jquery ajax form submit once on first submit, twice on second submit...?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a simple AJAX form that works as it should when I submit it. However, if I then enter new data into the same form (without refreshing the page), then it submits the form twice. If I do this a third time, then it submits the form three time, and so on. Why is it doing this? Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myForm").submit(function() {
        var myField = $('#myID).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'myFile.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {myData:myField},
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you copy and paste the code from your real code instead of typing out an extract?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even I got stuck with the same problem while developing a AJAX login form. After an googling for couple of hours I found a solution. I hope this should help you out.

Basically you have to **unbind** the current instance of form's submit action after your ajax request gets completed. 
So add this line before **return false;**

```
$("#myform").unbind('submit');
```

Therefore your entire code should look like

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myForm").submit(function() {
            var myField = $('#myID).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'myFile.php',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: {myData:myField},
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });

            /* Add this line */
            $("#myform").unbind('submit');
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hells yeah @Jack

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I found the solution in:
[jquery : submitting a form twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767871/jquery-submitting-a-form-twice)

Basicaly is adding .submit() to Saurabh Mishra answer:

```
$('#form1').unbind('submit').submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unbinding the form can break you Ajax from.  I found that as long as I declare the form first.

```
$('#my_form').ajaxForm
```

that all works as expected, and follows the standard protocol.  I just spent a day chasing the 'missing template' error on the form submission because I unbound the form.