# Why data is being submitted twice through ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, jquery

I am using codeiniter framework. I want to Submit form data in database throught ajax coll and after success submiting form process I want to refresh specific div through other ajax request.

But When I press Enter Key for submit form then data is being submitted twice. I want submit data by ajax once time with on enter key press.

My code like-

```
$('#form1').submit(function () {
var id = $('#id').val();
var comment_text = $('#comment_text').val();
$.ajax({
  data: {'id' :id,'comment_text':comment_text},
  type: "POST",
  url: "first_req.php",
  dataType : "json"
  success: function(data){
    if(data.status =="Success")
     {
    $.ajax({
      data: {'id':id},
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'sencond_req.php',
      contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
      success: function (data) {
        $('#com_display').html(data);
      }            
    });
     }
     }
    });
  return false;
      });
```

HTML-

```
<div id="com_display"></div>
<form id="form1" name="form1">
<input type='hidden' id='id' name='id' />
<input type='text' id='comment_text' name='comment_text' />
</form>
```

When I type hi in comment box and press enter button then data two times will be submitted in database.

Please give me any solution to solve it.

Comment: Just a small comment, why don't u make first_req.php call sencond_req.php when it finishes so u would save two requests to the user.

Comment: @Mohammed Joraid, I could not understand ur question( 
 
why php is related to this?)

Comment: oh sorry about that. All what i meant is, why php is being added as a question tag while it's not related to the question. As it seems, your issue is solely related to HTML and JQuery.

Comment: btw, there are two answers below. Kindly select the answer that provides u with the solution, if they don't, then pls leave a comment to let the answer writer know that his answer is not accurate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are submitting the data using ajax request, you are not stopping the default action of the form submit.

You can call the [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to do this.

```
$('#form1').submit(function (e) {
    //prevent the default form submission
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $('#id').val();
    var comment_text = $('#comment_text').val();
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            'id': id,
            'comment_text': comment_text
        },
        type: "POST",
        url: "first_req.php",
        dataType: "json"
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == "Success") {
                $.ajax({
                    data: {
                        'id': id
                    },
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'sencond_req.php',
                    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#com_display').html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

});
```

or `return false` from the event handler if you want to prevent the default and action and stop the bubbling of the submit event

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830542/prevent-double-submission-of-forms-in-jquery), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16814157/how-to-prevent-users-from-submitting-a-form-twice) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993047/why-does-my-jquery-ajax-form-submit-once-on-first-submit-twice-on-second-submit)

In the Documentation [READ HERE](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

***(Bind an event handler to the "submit" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.)***

In other words, when you click enter you will trigger default *submit* of the form, and also your jquery will submit the form.

Solution:

1. Prevent default behavior by adding  `e.preventDefault();`. Read -> [jQuery AJAX Form Submit Example](http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-form-submit/)

   > ```
   > $('#form1').submit(function (e) {        
   >     e.preventDefault();
   >     //the rest of code.
   > ```
2. remove default behavior

   > ```
   > $('form').submit(function(){
   >   $(this).find(':submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
   > });
   > ```

<strike>3. Only submit the form thru jquery when it actually submits (no resubmitting)</strike>

```
$(document).on("submit", "form.form1", function(event){
    alert(1);
});
```