# jQuery Ajax Post submitting form multiple times

Tags: ajax, jquery, post

We have a jsp form, which on a Button Click is submitted to a Struts2 Action Class. From the Action Class, the control flows to a Service (java) class and to a DAO (Java iBatis) class. The DAO class invokes a oracle pl/sql procedure.

**Problem:**

Reviewing the log statements in Action/Service/DAO & PL/SQL procedure shows that they are being invoked 2/3 times on a single button click. The number of times it executes is quite random, but it's never once (only in code deployed in Staging server).

***Strangely, this functionality works fine (invoked only once) when our code is deployed in our Development & Production servers (Websphere 7.1)***. The exact same code (EAR) when deployed in our Staging server is facing this multiple submit error.

We tried from various browsers (IE 8 & IE 9) and this issue occurs only when we try accessing the application deployed in our staging server.

all our Development, Staging & Production Websphere server is of same version & patch level.

Here is our javascript code used to submit.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                        mask();
                        var config = "${returnedCString}";

                        var f = "${flagS}";

                        if (f == "1"){
                            $.post('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/applyComp'
                                    ,function(data){
                                        unmask();

                                         $("#impactForm").attr('action','<%=request.getContextPath()%>/CompareForm');
                                         $("#impactForm").submit();     

                                    }

                             );
                }
}
```

The problem is that POST to the following Struts Action is what is happening multiple times

```
$.post('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/applyComp'
```

Comment: try to unbind the click after first submission. Check if the button is beeing clicked twice. OR its just the request which made twice

Comment: try this link if its helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767871/jquery-submitting-a-form-twice

Answer (score 1):

Add the submit action in this way:

```
$('.form_element').unbind('submit').bind('submit',function() {
    // do stuff here...
});
```