# Several ways of preventing a form to submit the normal way?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a little php experience and would like to learn ajax jQuery. I've been watching several tutorials on submitting a form without refreshing the page. I notice people use different ways to prevent a form from submitting the normal way (with a page refresh):

- with the event.preventDefault() function
- using return false
- In a script I'm trying to understand the JS script starts with:

  $("#submitBrandForm").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {

Does this also have the same functionality? This same script ends with 'return false', which confuses me (and makes me think the unbind - bind code has another purpose).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, the third one doesn't do the same thing. `unbind` only removes any previously attached event handlers (via `bind`), it does not prevent the form from being submitted.

In your example `unbind` and `bind` are just used to replace the existing event handler(s). If you don't unbind first, bind will add a handler to the ones that are already attached. You'll also often see `unbind('submit', ...)` inside the handler for a `submit` event that programmatically submits the form, to prevent the function from calling itself endlessly, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9767987/2092152).

By the way, `bind` and `unbind` have been deprecated, you should be using [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/).